# ASP.NET membership provider, custom login control

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, membership-provider, login-control

I'm using the ASP.NET membership provider on my website. It works fine while using the Login Control in Visual Studio. However, I feel the Login Control has its limitation and I'm having a hard time making it fit to the design of my page. So instead of using that Login control, I'd like to be able to just create two TextBox's and a Button myself and use that to login instead. So my question is, can I create a custom login page with by creating my own textbox's and buttons? The code behind Login.aspx that I use with the login control right now looks like this:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password) == true)
    {
        Login1.Visible = true;
        Session["user"] = User.Identity.Name;
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, true);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Invalid Login");
    }
}
```

I tried changing `Login1.UserName` to `TextBox1.Text` and so on, but that didn't work. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be removing Login1_Authenticate event and have a login button event to validate the credentials.

Or depending on how you submit back to server, such as ajax calls etc.
You can also use fiddler to see what's exactly being posted back to server.

PS. Why do not use ASP.net MVC?

Comment: Thank you! Don't know how I missed that, but at least it worked :) I don't use MVC because my teacher made us use WebForms when we started learning ASP.Net. I do realize that MVC would be better to use, but I've gotten so far on this project that I'll wait with MVC until I start a new one. Thanks again!